# Warnings and errors appearing on site after changing ubuntu user permissions Amazon EC2 server

Tags: 14.04, permissions, chmod, amazon-ec2, aws

My site is running on a EC2 Amazon server under Ubuntu/Apache2.

My site was running fine until I changed the permissions for user 'ubuntu' by doing this command:

```
chown -R ubuntu /var/www/html
```

Now my site is spitting out warning messages and errors :(

```
My site: www.kaysboutique.co.uk
```

I needed to do this as I was not able to write files via FileZilla (was getting permission denied).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run `sudo chown www-data -R /var/www/html/system/library/cache/` (If the webserver is not run as `www-data` please replace it with the user who runs Apache/Nginx)

If that doesn't fix all your error messages please run `sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/html/system`

Comment: is there a way to find out the user? i've tried with user 'ubuntu' as that's whats in /home/. But that didnt fix the errors.

Comment: Try www-data it's the most common @user3554072

Comment: @user3554072 if you _really_ cant find it try uploading [this PHP script](http://pastebin.com/FGJLQwTA) to your site and view it

Comment: Oh, oops didn't see the answer checked I'm glad I could help :)